# One man kidnapping job

Tags: logistics

I want person A to kidnap person B with no additional help. They're both women around 20 years old, and both fairly muscular, although person A is stronger. A should kidnap B while B is sleeping in a cave.
 Would it be reasonable for person A to be able to carry person B down a mountain all by herself? She doesn't have a car, or any other vehicle. Would she be able to abduct person B without waking a person nearby? Should person A drug person B with chloroform or something similar, and can that be done without person B making a lot of noise?

Comment: Does person A has a gun or other weapon?

Comment: If she got B unconscious enough not to make noise, making a improvised sled might help with the lack of strength. Also: spill some alcohol on the victim's mouse and shirt/jacket, so A could claim that she is just helping her drunk friend.

Comment: They have a dagger.

Comment: It seems rather pointless for the kidnapper to expend so much effort on such a risky venture. People are *heavy*. Easy to drop. Carrying them is exhausting (try it). People notice it. Instead, simply lie to her; lure her on her own feet to wherever the kidnapper can safely assume control.

Comment: You start in a cave.  So what's the point of struggling down a mountain, without any aid ?  Isn't keeping them in the cave equivalent to kidnapping in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all your questions is broadly: **yes**.

Or one by one:

> Would it be reasonable for person A to be able to carry person B down a mountain all by herself?

Yes, she could

- make a makeshift (improvised) [stretcher](https://www.base-medical.com/blog/diy-stretchers-to-carry-an-injured-person-out-of-the-wilderness)

  - This also allows you to tie up the drugged person and setup ropes (hoists) to lower them over particularly steep parts of a trail
- use a wagon, cart, or wheelbarrow
- [fireman carry](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2013/01/truth-about-little-women-carrying-big-wounded-men-combat/318986/) the person down the mountain

  - Note: This is the most known one-person carry but there are [a ton more](https://www.armystudyguide.com/content/powerpoint/First_Aid_Presentations/transport-a-casualty-usin-6.shtml) so one could also use any of the supine position drags or carries (where person is laying down or hanging on you) like the pack-strap, belt drag, or others.

The linked article for fireman carry points it out more fully but I can attest to carrying much larger people than myself (or wearing enough armor that this was true) for long distances & over bad terrain. Going down also helps as, well, its easier to run down a mountain than climb up.

If the hands need to be free I would suggest the suspect bring a solid (thick) belt and perform a Pistol-Belt Carry (image from old Army manual found on [Tpub](http://www.tpub.com/seabee/5-52.htm)):

[image: tpub belt carry]

> Would she be able to abduct person B without waking a person nearby?

Completely depends on her own skill and few other things:

1. How many trees, shurbs, and other concealing environmental objects are around.
2. The time of day (early morning, middle of the day, depends on the area but whatever time people are not around)
3. Is she able to disguise herself?

   - Make person look drunk
   - using the wheelbarrow then cover person in mesh, camo, and dirt
   - using a mover cart then put person in fridge box and dress yourself as a mover
4. Is the person drugged/unconscious and not making much noise because of this?

If any of these are true it could be done. There are many more, like it being a bad neighborhood and people just ignoring it, so just pick the ones you need and fit them to story.

> Should person A drug person B with chloroform or something similar, and can that be done without person B making a lot of noise?

Honestly, this depends on the story. However, having the person knocked out with anesthesia would definitely help with keeping it quiet.

Whether this was something "slipped" them when still awake (search for "roofy" - I do not feel comfortable putting that in this answer but its an option) or actually applying a anesthesia agent while the person is already asleep would completely depend on story but certainly both could be done without making noise (esp. the first as you just need person to have a "spiked" drink).

Answer (score 1):

This "not waking persons nearby" will be the problem. I'm sceptical that an inexperienced person could get a drugged/nonresponsible bodyweight down a slope *quietly.*

- You mentioned a dagger. Are threats of deadly force credible in your setting? The perpetrator wakes the victim with a hand over the mouth and a blade to the throat, says "no noise or I will cut."
- The perpetrator might gag and tie the victim if the slope is not to steep.

Of course there are plenty of things to go wrong in such a scenario, but as the writer you could have the victim act confused/intimidated and not confused/resisting.